# How to configure scroll speed using jquery animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I tried using the following code:

```
$('#divid').html(html).animate ({scrollTop:0}, "fast"); // Are slow, medium, fast parameters.
```

I also tired using this code:

```
$('#divid').html(html).animate ({scrollTop:0}, "500");
```

My end goal is have users be able to configure scroll speed and pass in that parameter to the animate function. But, both methods do not seem to make a difference in scroll speeds. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `animate` function expects duration to be either a string or a number.  Just pass it in as a number.

```
$('#divid').html(html).animate ({scrollTop:0}, 500);
```

Comment: What does 500 mean? It will complete the whole scroll in 500 msec?

Comment: @CSharper Look at the documentation for clarification on methods parameters. http://api.jquery.com/animate/